# Quote pickling limit

Tags: python

I've made this function that enables me to input a quote and an author and    then pickle them into a .txt file.

However, it seems that I may be limited to only one line of pickled information that I end up overwriting on when I execute the "enterquote" function. I cant seem to figure out how to put more information inside the file.

How could I do that?

```
 def readquote():
    f = open("quote.txt","r")
    pquote = pickle.load(f)
    pauthor = pickle.load(f)
    print "%3s\n - %s" % (pquote, pauthor)

def enterquote():
    f = open("quote.txt","w")
    quote = raw_input("What quote has its place in the quote book? \n to quit press Q\n\n")
    if quote != "Q":
        pickle.dump(quote, f)
        author = raw_input("what author said that? \n to quit press Q \n\n")
        pickle.dump(author, f)
        if author == "Q":
            print "goodbye"
    elif quote == "Q":
        print "goodbye"
    f.close()
```

I have tried this with shelf:

```
def readquote():
    f = shelve.open('quote.txt')
    psaying = f[quote["saying"]]
    pauthor = f[quote["author"]]
    for key in quote :
        print "%3s\n - %s" % (psaying, pauthor)


def enterquote2():
    f = shelve.open('quote.txt')
    quote = {}
    quote["saying"] = raw_input("What quote has its place in the quote book? \n to quit press Q\n\n")
    if quote != "Q":
        f['saying'] = saying
        quote[author] = raw_input("what author said that? \n to quit press Q \n\n")
        f['author'] = author
        if author == "Q":
            print "goodbye"
    elif saying == "Q":
        print "goodbye"


    f.close()
```

But it gives me an error on "psaying = f[quote["saying"]]"

I want to use the dictionnary format to couple saying and author into quote so that I could shelf them one after another, but it confuses me.

Comment: Use `open("quote.txt","a")`. See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).

Answer (score 0):

Pickling is for single objects. If you want to persistently save multiple objects, use the `shelve` module. It will provide you with a key-value store.

For example, you could change `enterquote` to the following:

```
def enterquote():
    f = shelve.open('quote')
    quote = raw_input("What quote has its place in the quote book? \n to quit press Q\n\n")
    if quote != "Q":
        f['quote'] = quote
        author = raw_input("what author said that? \n to quit press Q \n\n")
        f['author'] = author
        if author == "Q":
            print "goodbye"
    elif quote == "Q":
        print "goodbye"
    f.close()
```

You would then also want to modify your `readquote` function in a similar manner.

Comment: I dont understand how you can shelve another input on another shelve ( without the second overwriting on the first).